# If $L(H)$ is regular, then $H$ is either regular or semi-regular bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

If $H$ is a connected graph and $L(H)$ (line graph of $H$) is regular, then $H$ is either regular or semi-regular bipartite.

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to prove the above fact. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any vertex $y \in G$, write the degree of $y$ in $G$ as $d_G(y)$.

Let $v_0$ be a vertex, and for each nonnegative integer $i$, let $V_i$ denote the set of vertices $u_i$ where the shortest path between $v_0$ and $u_i$ has $i$ edges in $G$.

1. As $G$ is connected, every vertex is in one of the $V_i$s.
2. Furthermore, for each integer $i$ and each vertex $v_{i+1} \in V_{i+1}$, there is a path $P_{v_0v_{i+1}}$ of the form $P_{v_0v_{i+1}}=v_0u_1u_2 \ldots u_iv_{i+1}$, where $u_j \in V_j$ for each integer $j=1,2,\ldots, i$. Put another way, for each $u_{i+1} \in V_i$, there is a vertex $u_i \in V_i$ such that $u_iu_{i+1}$ is an edge in $G$.
3. Then also, iff $G$ is not bipartite, then there is integer $i$, and an edge $u_iv_{i}$; both $u_i \in V_i; v_{i} \in V_{i}$ in $G$. [This gives the odd cycle, and that this odd cycle is reachable from $v_0$ follows from 1., that $G$ is connected and every vertex is reachable from $v_0$.]

We make the following claim:

> Claim 1: So suppose that $G$ is not regular. then there are 2 integers $d_0$ and $d_1$ such that all vertices in $G$ have either degree $d_0$ or degree $d_1$ and that the degree of each edge in $G$ is $d_0+d_1$. Furthermore, every vertex in $V_{2k}$ for some integer $k$, has degree $d_0$, and every vertex in $V_{2k+1}$ for some integer $k$, has degeree $d_1$.

To see Claim 1, pick $v_0$ so that one of its neighbors $v_1$, has different degree from $v_0$ i.e., $d_G(v_0)  \doteq d_0 \not = d_G(v_1) \doteq d_1$. So then the degree of edge $v_0u_1$ in $G$ is $d_0+d_1$. By the fact that the degrees of edges $v_0u_1$; $u_1 \in V_1$; are all $d_0+d_1$, it follows that $d_G(u_1)$ must be $d_G(v_1) = d_1$ for each $u_1 \in V_1$. Likewise, the degrees of the edges $u_1u_2$; $u_1 \in V_1$; $u_2 \in V_2$, must all be $d_1+d_2$. This, and $d_G(u_1)=d_1$ for all $u_1 \in V_1$, and 2. above, give the degrees of each $u_2 \in V_2$ must satisfy $d_G(u_2)=d_G(v_0)=d_0$.

Continuing this reasoning down gives $d_G(u_3)=d_1$ for all $u_3 \in V_3$, and $d_G(u_4)=d_0$ for all $u_4 \in V_4$, and finally, $d_G(u_{2k}) = d_0$ for all $u_{2k} \in V_{2k}$, and $d_G(u_{2k+1})=d_1$ for all $u_{2k+1} \in V_{2k+1}$, for all integers $k$. And so by 1. above, if not all vertices in $G$ have the same degree, then there are 2 integers $d_0$ and $d_1$ such that all vertices in $G$ have either degree $d_0$ or degree $d_1$ and that the degree of each edge in $G$ is $d_0+d_1$. So Claim 1 follows.

We now finish.

> Claim 2: So suppose that $G$ is not regular. Then $G$ must be bipartite.

Now suppose that $G$ is not bipartite. But then it follows from 3. that there must be an integer $k$ and vertices $u_k,v_k \in V_k$ such that $u_kv_k$ is an edge in $G$. But then the degree of edge $u_kv_k$ is $2d_k \not = d_1+d_0$ no matter whether $k$ is odd or even. So it follows from Claim 1 that if not all vertices in $G$ have the same degree, then $G$ must be bipartite as well.

Comment: I am really grateful for your complete answer and your help.

Comment: @M.Ramana you are welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: I've learned some new things thanks to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

Let $d(u)$ be the degree of a vertex $u$. It may be helpful to rephrase the question as follows: "If the sum $d(u) + d(v)$ is the same for every edge $uv$ of $H$, then $H$ is regular or semi-regular bipartite."

Now pick any edge you like and consider two cases:

- Case 1, $d(u) = d(v)$. Try show then that *every* neighbor of $u$ must have the same degree as $u$, and use connectivity to go from there.
- Case 2, $d(u) \neq d(v)$. Try show every neighbor $w$ of $u$ has $d(w) = d(v)$, and every neighbor $x$ of $v$ has $d(x) = d(u)$, and use connectivity to go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your beautiful hints.